SOQL query in salesforce and the polymorphic relations
So I have a scenario where I have to Query a Promotion (based on ProductId, and/or BuyerGroupId) and also delete its related PromotionTier, PromotionTarget, PromotionQualifier etc...
So I want to write a query like this
select id,
(select id from promotionTiers),
(select id from PromotionTargets where Target.Tecsys_item_num__c = '654321')
from Promotion
but it is giving me following error
"No such column 'Tecsys_item_num__c' on entity 'Name'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names."
Now it migt be because the lookup field in PromotionTargets is TargetId and it is a polymorphic relation with (Product, Category)...
I am attaching a schema builder image as well so please have a look and let me know if there is any way to query the Promotions based on ProductId and BuyerGroupId... 
I have already mentioned what I have tried and what I am expecting

have you checked with Salesforce team if your SOQL executes successfully when ran directly on Salesforce?

You will need to use the TYPEOF operator in the soql query for polymorphic relationships: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_polymorphic_relationships.htm
